# Wordpress stylesheet child theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, parent-child

Actually my problem is that I already had a functional Child theme with a functions.php and many others filesname.php and also a style.css which work properly, but when I try to add an other stylesheet like for instance modules.min.css The theme is only reading it in the parent folder so I can't change stylesheets in my website and this is annoying

Some data:
File in the parent folder I want to override: \wp-content\themes\startit\assets\css\modules.min.css

File in the child folder I want to be readable: \wp-content\themes\startit-child\assets\css\modules.min.css

I also tryed to put the modules.min.css right here in my child theme next to the styles.css  but I can't override the parent folder \wp-content\themes\startit-child\modules.min.css

This is what look like my functions.php :

```
<?php
function startit_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'startit-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'startit_enqueue_styles' );

?>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do that and the simplest one is:

1. Remove/Dequeue Parent CSS file
2. Add/Enqueue new CSS file

   ```
   function PREFIX_remove_scripts() {
      wp_dequeue_style( 'put_modules_file_handler_here' );
      wp_deregister_style( 'put_modules_file_handler_here' );

      // Now register your child CSS here, using wp_enqueue_style
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'PREFIX_remove_scripts', 20 );
   ```

**Some Common Confusions**
Should you enqueue child styles as well as parent styles? Is it necessary? This is where a lot of confusion exists regarding enqueueing stylesheets in child themes. The answer depends on how the parent styles are included in the parent theme. For example, if the parent theme is using `get_stylesheet_uri()` to enqueue styles,

for example as in Twenty Sixteen:

```
wp_enqueue_style('twentysixteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri());
```

then you don't need to enqueue the child styles. This is because `get_stylesheet_uri()` returns the URL of the current active theme, which in this case is the child theme.

**This is how URLs are returned, when working with child themes**

```
get_stylesheet_uri()           = http://example.com/wp-content/themes/example-child/style.css
get_template_directory_uri()   = http://example.com/wp-content/themes/example-parent
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() = http://example.com/wp-content/themes/example-child
```

So, I would recommend you to check your parent `functions.php` and see, how the style is enqueued so you can handle it properly.

Comment: I have this in the functions.php of the parent folder `wp_enqueue_style('qode_startit_modules', QODE_ASSETS_ROOT.'/css/modules.min.css');` I will try to folow your advices step by step thank you even if it still seems hard for me, will be back to told you how it goes here in comment

Comment: It works using localhost, so this is always a good start thank you ! but online the same code doens't work (see the answer above I replied with the entire code, Thanks !

Comment: very strange, it should work on your live server. Double check and make sure everything is same on local and live server. And If it still doesn't work then get back with exactly problem OR error message...

Comment: Files and folders are exactly the same, I tryed to remplace the  `wp_dequeue_style('qode_startit_modules', QODE_ASSETS_ROOT.'/css/modules.min.css');` by `wp_dequeue_style('qode_startit_modules', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/modules.min.css');` but one of both `wp_dequeue_style` or `wp_deregister_style` does not work properly and I have no one error messages I'm sorry, can the path be different from the local and online website ?

Comment: Try clearing browser cache and also check, which file includes (parent or child) so you can further debug it.

Comment: Never mind, I just changed the file in the parent's folder and it works, I still learn a lot because it works in local, so big thanks to you and Good continuation ! (I upvoted and give the green tick to this answer, and puted the subget in [resolved]) Thanks again for the time you used for me !

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add css file or js file
function activate_css() {
wp_enqueue_style('min_style_css',  get_template_directory_uri() .'assets/css/modules.min.css'));
));
}
//add css
add_action( 'init','activate_css');
```

Comment: I tryed the following code because your got some error, but it still doesn't work, any ideas ? Thanks, the correction i made is :
`// Add css file or js file`
`function activate_css() {`
`wp_enqueue_style('min_style_css',  get_template_directory_uri() .'assets/css/modules.min.css');`
`}`
`//add css`
`add_action( 'init','activate_css');`

Comment: Hi! Any others ideas ? Because unfortunatly i'm still stuck,
Thanks !

Comment: Add this code in header.php "<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?= get_template_directory_uri() .'assets/css/modules.min.css'; ?>' type='text/css' media='all' />"