# How do child theme work for existing projects in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have created child theme for one of my existing project, How will it be usefull?

If i update parent theme all customization will be go away, What can i do in this scenario?

Comment: I was not sure about being a duplicate here, but you'll find useful iformations [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647028/wordpress-functions-php-child-theme). Basically it's the contrary, the goal is to be able to keep your modifications even if parent theme updates

Comment: A Child Theme acts as an 'override' to the Parent Theme.  Let's say you have a `header.php` in your Child Theme, it will override the `header.php` within the Parent Theme, despite you having updated it.  More information can be found at https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes If you look at the Source Code, you will find that the Parent Theme's CSS is loading first. 
 Then the Child Theme's CSS.  Since the Child Theme CSS files are loaded afterwards, it overrides the former Parent CSS Files.  Furthermore, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask this question.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, a child theme will supercede the parent theme. So even if the parent theme is updated Wordpress will take any data from the child theme that is present.

It is useful for giving you greater customisation and allowing you to create very specific templates, for specific kinds of post types and navigation, for example.